# How can I see global variables when debugging C/C++ in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am using Visual Studio Code and when I debug (I am debugging C++ code compiled with Clang) I see only local variables.
I do not see any global variables list.

How can I see all variables?

[image]

In this case I am inside a loop and I see only all the variables defined inside the loop, not the one defined outside.

Answer (score 19):

You will need to manually add global variables to a watch window.

1. Set a breakpoint
2. Start debugging (Debug -> Start Debugging or
   F5)
3. Open a Watch window (Debug -> Windows -> Watch -> Watch 1)
4. Type in the name of the variable manually

Comment: But I can not change the value, if it's in the Watch window...

Comment: Manually type isn't a long term solution.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio Code you can just go to the Watch pannel int the debug menu and click on + , then type the name of the variable you want to watch.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

After you follow the stepes in [Andrew L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49956136/5999372)'s answer you can modify the variable's value by the help of either:

**1. Debug Console**

[image]

**2. Address-Of Operator**

[image]

By prefixing the variable we want to watch with (&) we can now expand it and then right click on the dereferenced variable to set a value.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in previous answers, instead of the "VARIABLES" subview, use the "WATCH" subview, press the "+" button, and type the name of the global variable you want to watch. Ex. `my_global_variable`, or if there are any namespaces involved, `my_top_level_namespace::my_inner_namespace::my_global_variable`.

If there are any [unnamed namespaces](/q/357404/11107541) involved, you might need to find out the [mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) of the variable and use that instead (not sure what else you would/could do, actually). One way if you're using gcc to find it is to dig through `nm -nC path/to/my_executable_filename | less`.

Note that if the global variable temporarily shows up in the VARIABLES subview at any point, you could also right click it there and select "Add to watch".

In the latest version of the C/C++ extension, editing global variables from that subview should also be supported (right click the variable and click "Set Value"), [though at some point in the past](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9019#issuecomment-1374263063) it was broken, which could be worked around by writing the expression for the address of that variable (Ex. `&my_variable`), and then expanding that item in the subview to get to the value of the variable, and then right click and do "Set Value" there.